# RAM progressively increasing in Debian VPS

Tags: linux, debian, vps, ovh

I have a VPS that has below configuration:

1. Debian OS
2. 16 GB RAM
3. 320 GB SSD
4. NGINX
5. Plesk Admin Panel

There are just a few wordpress websites hosted on this server that have no more than a few visitors a day. Everything is working perfect but RAM usage is wired. It progressively increase everyday without change in traffic or anything. It takes about 15-20 days for it to reach 100%. After that the server stops working & I need to reboot the server. After reboot, the RAM usage resets to 5% and server again start working blazingly fast. Please suggest the cause and solution. There is almost no load at server at all.

Here is my usage stats for a month:

[Server Usage Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMGpb.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question to add some more detailed memory diagnostics while experiencing high memory pressure. As a starting point: contents of  `/proc/meminfo`  and the top few jobs by memory: `top -b -o %MEM | head -n 12`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind most memory monitors for linux are just wrong (they are, really), and alert on available free mem, which is practically meaningless for linux. If your "problem" is available free mem then you don't have a problem. In linux you need to check for swapping (sar -B / -S) and tuning parameters. Forget about "free memory" - linux always tries to use all your memory.